# What does Prevention mean here?

Tags: word-meaning

Look at this excerpt from the global ethics of tourism code:

> It is the task of the public authorities to provide protection for tourists and visitors and their belongings; they must pay particular attention to the safety of foreign tourists owing to the particular vulnerability they may have;
>   they should facilitate the introduction of specific means of information, **prevention, security**, insurance and assistance consistent with their needs. ([source](http://dtxtq4w60xqpw.cloudfront.net/sites/all/files/docpdf/gcetbrochureglobalcodeen.pdf))

I do not understand the meaning of prevention in this context? How is it different from security?

Comment: Security is taking an active role to react in the case of needing to protect tourists. Prevention relates to trying to stop any incident before protection is needed. Think about signs warning of the presence of pickpockets/cash-point scammers. These would be considered preventative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means exactly the same as it does elsewhere. Stopping something before it happens.

From dear Google.

> **prevention**
>
> prɪˈvɛnʃn/
>
> noun
>
> noun: prevention
>
> the action of stopping something from happening or arising.
>       "crime prevention"